# How to get Kubernetes cluster zone names?

Tags: go, kubernetes

I would like to know if there is any way to retrieve cluster zone names in Kubernetes API.
I am using IBM dev cluster. As of now I got list of Nodes via k8s API using Go library and I can get zone information from node labels but this will be expensive way to get zone names. Would like to know if there is any other method which i can use to get zone names.

Comment: Isn't [this](https://unofficial-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin/multiple-zones/#nodes-are-labeled) what you're looking for?

Comment: While we're on it, 1) The language [is called Go](https://go.dev/doc/faq#go_or_golang); 2) You seem to misunderstand the terminology around accessing k8s: what is called "an API" (to be precise, it should have been called "web API" or "HTTP API") is the specification of accessing k8s using HTTP requests. You can do them using anything which speaks HTTP. What you're using is called "Go client libraries for k8s", not "Go API".

Comment: Thanks for making things clear kostix. I want to get names of zones in cluster using Go client libraries for k8s. I am able to get list of nodes and could retrieve zone names from Node labels but this method would be tedious.